# Text-based game movement

Tags: java

I'm making a text-based game and I would like my hero to be able to move within a 3x3 grid. I tried doing this with a two-dimensional array fairly easily. The problem that I encountered was that I wanted to call a method for each grid the hero was in. So if the hero was in grid 0,0 then I would call the atHouse() method, if he went to 0,1 I call the atTree() method. Each of those methods would give a description of that area, items in it, etc...

So, since I wasn't able to store methods in an array I was thinking of possibly doing another way. I just don't know what way might be the best. Has anyone setup a world in a quality way that is better than what I described?

Comment: Why can't you store methods in an array? How about an array of e.g. `Place` objects with the methods you want?

Comment: You could have the indices of the 2D array map to function calls of some sort of caller object. Or maybe I don't understand the question...

Comment: Could you share a bit of the code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a factory method:

I'd suggest a 2d array with names for each position:

```
[
    ["House", "Tree", "etc"],
    ["etc", "etc", "etc"],
    ["etc", "etc", "etc"]
]
```

Then, you'd pass the position into your factory method which would grab the function name for to use in a switch. Obviously, this solution is not the best, as you'll have to explicitly define each method call.

```
public void runMethod(int row, int col)
{
    string mName = myArray[row][col];

    switch(mName)
    {
        case "House":
            atHouse();
        break;
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea. I understand that it could work, but it feels like I'm adding code in too many spots. So I get your point of stating that it's not the best solution. What might be a more elegant solution?

Comment: This seems to be the best option. It makes sense to me and, right now, that's all that matters. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would think an array of a base class, call it `location` with a `describe()` method would be the best way to do this. Then you can subclass a `house` class and a `tree` class.

Or you could just create instances of `location` and set a description property.

Comment: So like Location[][] locations = { Location.atHouse(), Location.atTree(), ...} or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing objects in an array you could define a method which would take position as param. 
Say position 1 means hero is in 0,0 and position 2 means hero is in 0,1.
You could define a method as:

```
public void heroMoved(int position){
  switch(position){
    case 1:
           call method associated
           break;
    case 2:
           call method associated
           break;
        .
        .
        so on
}
}
```

Comment: I see what your saying. But since I would rather have two values, like a coordinate point, I guess I could have nested switch statements or if statements. So like 1 then 1,2 or 3; 2 then 1,2,3; 3 then 1,2,3; to make it a 3x3. Not bad. Thanks.